# How to add syntax highlighting for custom methods in Atom for Ruby

Tags: ruby, syntax-highlighting, atom-editor

For example, in the following class, I want syntax highlighting for 
`helper_method(@x, @y)` (line 1 in the main method.)

```
class test
  def new(x, y)
    @x = x
    @y = y
  end

  def main
    result = helper_method(@x, @y)
    puts result
  end

  def helper_method(x, y)
    // do stuff with x, y
  end
end
```

I wonder why the current highlighting scheme doesn't do that as it seems valuable to me to see where I call my methods and where I just use baked-in commands and expressions. Can I change that, for Atom?

Here some screenshots to further illustrate my problem:

In the first screenshot I expect `get_time_limit_for_source(order_source)` to be highlighted:

[image]

It is a method that is defined in the same class:

[image]

Interestingly, in my example code, the highlighting is exactly as I want it:

[image]

The highlighting in the test class is as I want it, but in this case is due to the use of the helper word which triggers highlighting when `language-ruby-on-rails` is installed/activated.

Comment: In this particular case, a screenshot would be more helpful than the code.

Comment: True, but it should still be clear what I want, or isn't it?

Comment: Not really, could you show a screenshot so I can see how your own method is rendered as opposed to a "baked in" one?

Comment: Alright, will edit in a minute!

Comment: And just for clarification, do you want to highlight only that method (or a set of particular methods) or any custom method (although I'm not sure what than means)?

Comment: I want the methods I defined myself (how would you call those?) to be highlighted when called. I hope the screenshots make it clear what I want.

Comment: `helper_method` is probably highlighted because of the [`language-ruby-on-rails`](https://atom.io/packages/language-ruby-on-rails) package.

Comment: your right, changing the method name to sth without `helper` removed the syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Atom` is an Electron app, based on Chrome. Feel free to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> and examine whatever you want with Chrome Developer Tools:

[image]

As you can see, the local method call is not granted with any class, therefore it is impossible to style it without patching the syntax highlighter. For those elements having the class[es], one might simply `Edit` ⇒ `Stylesheet` in the main menu and update the CSS.